# Django XML on Request

Tags: django, django-views

I have a problem

In my views.py I have a method that takes xml from the POST and does some stuff.

```
def check_xml(request):
    try:
        # get the XML records from the POST data
        xml = request.raw_post_data
```

This works great I can test it using:

```
xml_data = """<root><a><b>Hello</b><\a></root>""" 
h = Http()
resp, content = h.request("http://myurl/check_xml", "POST", xml_data)
```

However, In my view I have another function which I want to call check_xml()

```
# i construct some xml using lxml.etree
myrequest.raw_post_data = new_xml
check_xml(myrequest)
```

I would rather not have to call the url, seeing as i am calling another method in my views.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to call `check_xml()` from another method in your `views.py` without having to post a request to `http://myurl/check_xml`?

Comment: yes exactly. maybe i should have a second optional param def check_xml(request, xml=None)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the part of `check_xml()` that manipulates the `XML` object in its own method independent from the request object:

```
def xml_function(xml):
  #do what you have to do with the `xml` arg
  ...
```

the call it in `check_xml()` and in any other method (direct call (no requests)).

```
def check_xml(request):
    try:
        # get the XML records from the POST data
        xml = request.raw_post_data
        ...
        xml_function(xml)
        ...

def other_function():
    ...
    xml_function(new_xml)
    ...
```

Comment: @Mark, set manji's response here as the answer. This lets other StackOverflow user's in your same boat know there's a verified answer available here.